# Server not recognizing disconnect when TCP client is forcibly closed

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

## Introduction

A single instance of my client application will make two outgoing TCP connections to the remote server - a *main connection* and a *file transfer connection*.

When the client application is forcibly closed -  *sometimes* the server does not acknowledge that both of the socket connections have been dropped.

The server will either detect that both connections have been dropped or that only the *main connection* has been dropped which is undesirable.

Understand that the problem occurs on only one of several test machines and that the *file transfer connection* is actively transmitting data when the client is forcibly closed.

Having analyzed the network traffic -  I learned that the OS was in fact acknowledging two *RST* flags! Because of this I am inclined to believe that the problem lies with the server code.

## Code

Using the `Socket.BeginReceive` method, my callback which is predominantly responsible for detecting disconnections looks like this:

```
private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
{
    try 
    {
        int bytesTransferred = _clientSocket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
        _logger.Debug(GetHashCode() + " Received " + bytesTransferred + " bytes from " + RemoteEndPoint);

        if (bytesTransferred > 0) 
        {
            _clientSocket.BeginReceive(_readMessageBuffer, ReadCallback);
            _logger.Debug(GetHashCode() + " Issued asynchronous read for " + RemoteEndPoint);
        } 
        else 
        {
            _logger.Debug(GetHashCode() + " Client disconnected. Received zero bytes. ");
        }
    } 
    catch (SocketException socketException) 
    {
        _logger.DebugException(GetHashCode() + " Client disconnected. SocketException thrown", socketException);
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException objectDisposedException)
    {
        _logger.DebugException(GetHashCode() + " Client disconnected. ObjectDisposedException thrown", objectDisposedException);
    }
    catch (Exception exception) 
    {
        _logger.DebugException(GetHashCode() + " Client disconnected. Exception thrown", exception);
    }
}
```

In order to isolate the problem I have stripped the code back so that the server *only* issues an asynchronous read each time a portion of data is read from the network.

Could somebody please share some insight or speculation as to why on certain machines the server application will not always detect both socket disconnections?

---

[This is the unmodified log produced when the server application *fails* to acknowledges that both underlying socket connections have been dropped.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3bdd19a55a63460f2186)

[This is the unmodified log produced when the server application *successfully* acknowledges that both underlying socket connections have been dropped.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5df8438c23f6e734d961)

Comment: your code looks fine, the only thing i can point out is `if (socketError == SocketError.Success)` is not needed when 0 byte is received.

Comment: and what you mean by `the file transfer connection remains in a half-open state`? if you are trying to close the second connection when the first connection drops you may have to link both and shut down the other one manually.

Comment: Please post more code, anything that might be relevant. Did you see the RST when the server did not notice the disconnect, or did you just generally observe a RST. Are you open to workarounds (thinking of timeouts and keepalive packets)?

Comment: @usr I really do appreciate that it is hard to believe but in an attempt to isolate the problem - the server application simply issues asynchronous reads for each the child socket as depicted above. The actual data read from the network is effectively ignored and there are no other operations in process.

Comment: @usr The *RST* is *always* acknowledged by the server. I do not want to abstract or hide the problem using a keep alive.

Comment: Where do you see that server detects that main connection is closed? I would imagine that it sometimes detects that file connection is closed. Ungracefully closed connection can only be detected if there's activity. Or you need to enable tcp keep alives.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I see is that there is no exception handler around the Socket.EndReceive call.  That call can indeed throw exceptions.

You are using the version that is supposed to return a SocketError, but nothing in the docs says that it does that in all cases.

Because ReadCallback is called by the system you won't have any exception handlers further up the chain that could even catch and print an error when an exception is thrown by EndReceive.  Thus it will appear that nothing has really gone wrong but the socket is left half open.

I suggest adding the exception handler around Socket.EndReceive and printing a message or setting a breakpoint there when it happens.  I think that will point to the problem.  You probably just need to dispose/close the Socket when you get an exception from EndReceive.

Hope that helps - Harold

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  If the client becomes unreachable this will happen (such as if you unplug the network cable on the client computer).  You need to set a timer for when you want to cancel your async read when this happens.

Comment: Updated the question in an attempt to make the problem clearer and have also offered a bounty. Maybe you have further speculations.

Comment: Hi Caster - The only other thing I can think of is that when you call BeginReceive the first time (outside of the code you posted) that you are not catching exceptions there either.  Have you checked that case?  Harold

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The thing about computer networking is that messages travel across a network. There is no psychic link between them. If one endpoint just *disappears*, if the network breaks or the computer loses power, there is no psionic signal sent off to the other end saying "I am no longer able to talk to you".

So the only way to *reliably* find out if the computer you're talking to is still there, is to try to talk to it. When the network fails to deliver packets to the computer, then you find out. But when a computer goes from "saying nothing because it has nothing to say", to "saying nothing because it isn't there", all your end is seeing is just that it's saying nothing. You can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code. This is a good explanation of what's going on: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37490/Detection-of-Half-Open-Dropped-TCP-IP-Socket-Conne

In short, you have to use some kind of keep alive messages to test you connection. If the client process simply dies, the server might never get a notification about it and will never become aware of it.

Some more reading:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/nettracer/archive/2010/06/03/things-that-you-may-want-to-know-about-tcp-keepalives.aspx